# unable to delete an old pointer (segfault)

Tags: c++

I'm confused as to why one of these would work and the other would not.  I'm trying to enable switching of camera controllers, in both cases the (mostly) copy constructor succeeds, the first branch is segfaulting on the `delete` though

```
if (type == controllers::Camera::Type::Arcball) {
    controllers::Camera *old_cam = mController;
    mController = new controllers::ArcballCamera(*old_cam);
    delete old_cam;//!!! this segfaults
    return true;
}
else if (type == controllers::Camera::Type::Fly) {
    controllers::Camera *old_cam = mController;
    mController = new controllers::FlyCamera(mGLFWWindow, *old_cam);
    delete old_cam;
    return true;
}
```

Does anybody have suggestions for what could be going on here?  The second branch works fine (can `delete old_cam;`).

Comment: Just because something doesn't crash doesn't mean it's correct. You're absolutely certain `mController` was always created with a scalar new expression? `Camera` has a virtual destructor?

Comment: Hmmmm you're definitely onto something, the `ArcballCamera` is the only one that actually does anything in the destructor.  I will inspect those, I added an "other than smartpointers" likely after you commented.  I will post back, likely asking you to make your comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not properly shutting down a thread in the `FlyCamera`, the thread captured `this`, which is where the eventual segfault was occurring.  Thank you @aschepler for pointing out what should have been obvious, the destructors were the the problem which should have been apparent from the fact that one could be deleted, but the other could not!